# Jquery add class on page view

Tags: jquery

I have added

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

window.scroll

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    if (isScrolledIntoView('h2') === true) {
        jQuery('h2').addClass('in-view')
    }
    else {jQuery('h2').removeClass('in-view')
    }
});
```

The problem is that the classes are added and removed when the top h2 on the page is visible. I would like each h2 to be triggered when each individual one enters the browser window.

Please forgive me, I am fairly new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's already working for the first `h2`, you can simply use [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to repeat it for the other `h2` elements:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    $("h2").each(function() {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('in-view')
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('in-view')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, works perfectly! Well it did when i added }); instead of just }

Comment: @ADRIAN I fixed the syntax error in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This works great, except that the h2 elements that should be visible when the page loads dont show until the page is scrolled. Is there a way to make the page load with the class added already to the visible h2 elements?

Comment: @ADRIAN When the page loads, you can use `$(window).scroll();` to trigger the event.

Comment: @ADRIAN calling `.scroll()` without any parameters will trigger the scroll event, which will run your code initially. You can put it directly after your current defined scroll event.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again for your help! 

Out of interest, why does this not trigger all the events, why only the ones visible?

Comment: @ADRIAN I don't understand the question.

Comment: Don't worry about it, its my lack of knowledge. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the code to each h2 element

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    $("h2").each(function{
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('in-view')
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('in-view')
        }
    });
});
```